# What is an iOS (and OS X) API to get the Unicode category of a character?

Tags: ios, unicode, categories

For OS X there is UCGetCharProperty, which, although it does smell a bit semi-obsolete, looks usable.

(EDIT: Ignore this part, it's an "ell", not an "1"... What does the "Gen1" part of kUCCharPropTypeGenlCategory mean? "1st generation"? Are the possible categories ones from some obsolete version of the Unicode standard?)

Comment: `kUCCharPropTypeGenlCategory` stands for ["General Category"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category). It's an "ell", not a "one".

Comment: ah. that's what I get from just reading the docs without actually typing it;) Still, the main question stands, as UCGetCharProperty is not available on iOS (unless the documentation is wrong?)

Comment: You are right, it seems to be not available on iOS (and I don't know a direct replacement). - What information do you really need? If you are only interested if a character is letter, digit, punctuation … then you can use the methods from `NSCharacterSet` / `CFCharacterSet`.

Comment: I am experimenting to see whether I can replace the use of the (huge) ICU library (and database) (compiled statically into an app) with suitable use of system APIs instead. One thing that the code wants to do is find out the Unicode category of arbitrary Unicode code points. (The codebase in question is LibreOffice...)

Comment: Anyway, I guess it would be fairly trivial to write a script that reads UnicodeData.txt and generates code to construct the CFCharacterSets corresponding to the different categories, and mappings from code point to category. Might be hard to generate code and/or come up with a table encoding that isn't awfully bloated or slow, though.

Comment: Watch the wwdc2013 session on Core Text they covered this.

Comment: I notice that <unicode/uchar.h> *is* part of the ICU subset that is public in the iOS SDK, so I could use the ICU subset for this functionality, I guess.